# Simple script to replace Apache's mod_autoindex with a user-friendly directory listing

Tags: php, perl, apache, directory-listing, mod-autoindex

The Apache module [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html) generates "directory indexes" that show users a crude hyperlinked list of the files and directories inside a directory (when there is no index.html or other [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) file).

I have a directory on an Apache webserver where I want to provide an automatic directory listing, including the full filenames, sorted most-recently-modified-first, with file sizes displayed, using simple and attractive presentation. I cannot use mod_autoindex or other Apache features.

I am therefore looking for a simple script that does much the same thing as mod_autoindex. In other words I want a script I can put in a directory that outputs an HTML document to STDOUT that contains a hyperlinked list of the files in the directory.

The script should present its output in a simple & attractive way (non-technical people will be using it), consist of one file that I can edit if required, and preferably be OS-independent (so I can use it again later). Extra features would be great, but ease of install is all-important (though I am happy to tweak the code if I have to).

My preference is for a perl script (i.e. an index.pl file), but PHP would be acceptable  (index.php). Those are the only DirectoryIndex options on the server.

**Update**

I have decided to use [snif](http://www.bitfolge.de/snif-en.html) in preference to [AutoIndex](http://autoindex.sourceforge.net/) to solve the current problem, but I am still interested in finding a perl implementation, so if you know of one please post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

snif is nice and I think meets all your needs.
[Link](http://www.bitfolge.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=66:snif-simple-and-nice-index-file&catid=38:eigene&Itemid=59)

Comment: Better. I have used snif because it is relatively easy to tweak, isn't too big, and because nobody has posted a perl solution.

Comment: i am in a shared hosting env and i want to use a custom directory listing script. what should i do?

Comment: Thanks to WayBack Machine Page Backed To Life [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140724000351/http://bitfolge.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=66:snif-simple-and-nice-index-file&catid=38:eigene&Itemid=59)

Answer (score 1):

I guess [AutoIndex](http://autoindex.sourceforge.net/) could solve your problem.

Comment: I gave it a try, and it fits the description, but it does too much and is too large and confusing. Close though, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

in your httpd.conf file or with:

use Apache::Icon ();
   use Apache::AutoIndex;

from : 
cpansearch.perl.org/src/GOZER/Apache-AutoIndex-0.08/AutoIndex.pm

from:
http://www.google.com/search?num=20&q=perl+Apache%3A%3AAutoIndex